# How to fix the enviroment variable GDAL_DATA path set?

Tags: python, environment-variables, pycharm, anaconda, gdal

I have been work with gdal in python 2.7 in windows 10 and Pycharm, and I can't fix the GDAL_DATA path in the environment. Because that I got this message:

> ERROR 4: Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv.  Try setting the GDAL_DATA environment variable to point to the directory containing EPSG csv files.

I try to use command line:

```
set GDAL_DATA='c:/Users/User/share/epsg_csv/'
```

And try to use the function inside the python code:

```
import os
os.environ["GDAL_DATA"] = 'c:/Users/User/share/epsg_csv/'
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you try removing the trailing '/'? Just a guess.

Comment: you ensured that `gcs.csv` is in that path?

Comment: @WilmarvanOmmeren Yes. When I try to run something in the command line for example, 
        "gdalwarp input.tif reprojected6.tif -overwrite -of GTiff -r near -ot Int16 -tr 0.00254328 0.00254328 -t_srs "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84"
                                                                                                                                         and I indicated the path of GDAL_DATA it works. 
But, when I try to use the gdal warp inside of some python script I can't fix it.

Comment: @RutgerKassies I have been try whithout "/", whithout "C:/"...

Answer (score 4):

For some reason that I do not understand the `GDAL_DATA` variable (and for that matter also the `PROJ_LIB` variable) are not set at installation of the GDAL packages with Anaconda 4.6.

To set these variables I do the following at the start of the program before calling any of the geo modules.

```
import os
os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = os.environ['CONDA_PREFIX'] + r'\Library\share\gdal'
os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = os.environ['CONDA_PREFIX'] + r'\Library\share'
```

For information for my conda environment the CONDA_PREFIX is:

```
c:\Users\<user_name>\Ananconda3\envs\<my_env>
```

Hope this helps.